# How to install WooCommerce Language pack maually?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, language-packs

I am using WordPress 6.0.1 and WooCommerce 6.7.0

I need to install Arabic (RTL) Language pack manually.

I searched every possible post online and can't make it to work.

I tried to set default WordPress language to Arabic but this didn't solve the problem.

My theme is U-Design and it fully support Arabic and RTL.

Many strings need to be translated by PolyLang.

I tried to upload the language pack to `wp-content/languages/plugins/` & to `wp-content/languages/woocommerce` & to `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/i18n/languages`
But no luck!

Can any one please direct me to a way to install Arabic Language pack manually?

Update:

I tried exactly what is suggested in [this document](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-localization/).

And downloaded [language pack from here](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/).
But still no luck!

Thank you

Comment: did you make properly the step 5?
5/ Rename this file to  woocommerce-YOURLANG.mo (e.g., Great Britain English should be en_GB).

Comment: @Keevstudio Yes I did, It should be `woocommerce-ar_SA.mo` and still didn't work!